# can't bind button onClick

Tags: android, button, data-binding, onclick

I'm facing a strange issue in my app. I can't bind a button's onClick event to a method.  Here's my code:

```
public class BookingViewModel extends BaseObservable {
    public void onAddInvite(View view) {
        invitationList.add(new Person(name, number, email)); 
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.invitationsText);
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="bookingViewModel"
            type="it.jgrassi.roombooking.viewmodel.BookingViewModel" />
    </data>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_book"
            android:layout_width="89dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="Book"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:enabled="@{bookingViewModel.bookingEnabled}"
            android:onClick="@{bookingViewModel::onAddInvite}"/>
</layout>
```

I find it strange because in the same app I have a similar situation handling the onClick on a list item:

```
public class ItemRoomViewModel extends BaseObservable{
public void onItemClick(View view) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="roomViewModel"
            type="it.jgrassi.roombooking.viewmodel.ItemRoomViewModel" />
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_room"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="@{roomViewModel::onItemClick}"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">
</layout>
```

all other bindings work perfectly fine. also android studio make the method look like is being used. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `android:clickable="true"` in the button, as you did in the working case. You can use click listeners instead to catch the click event. Also, you can use [Butter Knife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) (click for more information) for field and method bindings (that's what I'm using now).